# Rails 3, will-paginate; How to show multiple items in a row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gridview, will-paginate

So I'm trying to Paginate an array of items on a page in a grid format, with 3 items per row. It should allow for 6 rows per page. Similar to this, actually: http://www.logicbuy.com/ 
It seems like it should be relatively simple to implement with will-paginate, but I can't find any information on the web or on this site. Any ideas?

Comment: `will_paginate` is just supplying pagination support for you. You'll have to setup the grid in the view on your own. You can specifically tell `will_paginate` that the page size is 27 (3*6) though.

Comment: Ok, so I should still paginate on the Coupon table, and tell it to put (18?) items on each page. Right now I just have 'render @coupons' and 'will_paginate' in my coupon index page, and that renders a bunch of _coupon partials. Should I put the grid formatting in the index page, or in the partials?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the wiki pages for `will_paginate` https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/. You can specify the page size in your find like:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 18
end
```

Then find your coupons `@coupons = Coupon.paginate :page => params[:page]` and `render @coupons` like you already are doing.

And finally, provide the pagination links, `<%= will_paginate @coupons %>`.

Let me know if you need any more explanation or help, but I suggested reading over the wiki pages if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I have read the wiki pages and my code looks very similar to what you presented. It paginates correctly with 18 items per page, but it shows 18 coupons in a single column (18X1) and I want a (6X3) grid. There doesn't seem to be a 'per_row' parameter, would I have to modify the will_paginate code to get this functionality?

Comment: yea, you would need to modify how your coupons are rendered via the partial or something (change the html/css). Go ahead and accept my story if you think it was helpful. If you need html/css style answers for your render call, I suggest posting another SO question for that.

Comment: That's what my original question was; how to get a grid layout when using will-paginate. The problem is I can't just change the html, because the partial takes a local variable that is a single coupon, and I don't see how I can render 3 coupons in a horizontal row when I only have access to one coupon in the partial. Does that make sense? I thought this would be a common problem..

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was misled by the question since this really has nothing to do with `will_paginate`. You'd have the same problem if you weren't using that gem. You'll have to apply some CSS to each coupon block that is rendered. A common approach is to use the CSS float property to align blocks of html to the right/left of one another.